# Android, Launch shortcuts of other applications programmatically

Tags: android

I want to **launch** shortcuts of ***other*** applications programmatically.
is that even possible? and how?

---

I have an application installed on my phone, this application has a shortcut to do something, I want to RUN (LAUNCH) this shortcut by my own application

Comment: It must be possible, the Secure Settings plugin for Tasker can do it. If you can't figure out how it's done, you can always set up a Tasker profile that listens for a broadcast intent and launches the shortcut using Secure Settings. Not really useful for production apps, however.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a permission such as

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

and will need to create an intent shortcut for another app. The above duplicate gives a good starting point.

I would assume you need to know which Activity to call in your intent of the other apps

Comment: It is not answering the question how to *run* a shortcut which is already exists (some other application created it).
Why the whole Internet focused on just two things - how to create a shortcut, or how to send an intent?